# How to remove the jitter from my pong AI movement?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, ai, monogame

I am developing Pong using Monogame / XNA and my AI paddle is really jittery when the ball is moving more horizontally than vertically.

My AI is very simple and works as follows:

- If the ball's position is greater than the paddle position I increase
  the paddle's y position by 3
- If the ball's position is less than the paddle position I decrease
  the paddle's y position by 3

Where is the flaw in my logic that would cause jittering when the ball is moving more horizontally than vertically?

Comment: These types of "how to fix my code" type questions typically aren't well received. You may want to instead talk about the algorithm you're using, what's wrong with it and how you want it to work. Right now it's not clear why your code is written the way it is, so it's hard to tell what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your algorithm doesn't account for is if the ball's vertical speed is less than your paddle's speed (in your specific scenario, 3).

Consider the following example:

- The ball is moving perfectly horizontally (y speed is zero)
- The AI paddle uses a vertical speed of 3 units as in your exact scenario
- The paddle's y position is 10
- The ball's y position is 11
- List item

How this will play out is as follows:

- Frame 1: The paddle is lower than the ball. We increase the paddle's
  y position by 3. The paddle's new y position is 13 while the ball's y
  position remains 11
- Frame 2: The paddle is now higher than the ball. We decrease the
  paddle's y position by 3. The paddle's new y position is 10 (same as
  the original position) while the ball's y position remains 11.
- Frame 3: Repeats the same as frame 1.
- Frame 4: Repeats the same as frame 2.
- Frame N: You're stuck in a loop here until the ball actually moves
  vertically and only after the ball has moved more than 3 units.

An algorithm that you could potentially use that would fix the above problem is to modify your exact algorithm but also accommodate for when the difference between the paddle's y position and the ball's y position is less than the paddle's vertical speed.

- If the ball's y position is less than 3 units greater or lower than the paddle's y position then set the paddle's y position to be the same as the ball's y position.